# Touchscreen not working on a Dell Inspiron Duo

Tags: 11.10, touchscreen

Screen on my Dell Inspiron Duo is not working with Ubuntu 11.10, though it worked when I initially installed it (~one week ago).

Another note: the touchscreen works with Windows 7 (dual boot).

Comment: I've been searchin for a solution as well.. what happened is the kernel got updated (version 3.* now) which breaks the drivers. The new touchscreen drivers can be downloaded that were made specifically for 3.* kernels but its a different configuration then before.. for example I've gotten the touchscreen working again but I can't configure the touch points. If I touch the top of the screen it clicks the bottom and vice versa.. I think a custom kernel has to be compiled and the drivers need to be configured properly.. (bangs head on desk).. I hope a solution is found soon.. untill then I contin

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem like you. Touchscreen was not working anymore on my Inspiron duo after update to kernel 3.xI. I found the solution here:

- http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.com/2011/08/howto-linux-on-dell-inspiron-duo.html

Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Set:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="usbhid.quirks=0x0eef:0x725e:0x40"
```

Run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot your system. Your touchscreen will now work again.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware issue!

The problem is that the magnets both in the corners of the screen as well as the back bottom of the laptop when folded into tablet mode affect the capacitative screen.

The solution:

1. Carefully pry open the screen back, no screws, just plastic catches.
2. Put two M2x20 screws on the outside edge of the magnets, the magnets will hold them there. This distorts the nearby magnetic field away from the screen
3. Your touchscreen should now become one hundred percent reliable except when folded into tablet mode. To fix that, unscrew all the screws on the bottom of the laptop, then carefully pry open the case (similarly, all plastic catches). There should be magnets both facing up (the keyboard side of the case) and down (towards the laptop base, and towards the screen when in tablet mode.) Remove the magnets facing toward the screen side entirely. Adding M2 screws here may also work but I have not tried that.
4. You should now have a fully functioning, 100% operational touchscreen in all folding orientations.